# Issue in Mocking restTemplate in unit test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, resttemplate, spring-boot-test

So i am new to testing
We have a function

```
Fn(){
   restTemplate.postForEntity(url)
   }
```

Now while writing the test for this we need to mock this call and return a dummy object with mock data.

I have tried multiple methods :

1- Mocking restTemplate using

```
@Mock
RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;
```

2- Mocking the server to return the object.

But in all case it is diving inside the function and making the API call.

Also the url is defined inside the yml file and we are using @Value to get it in the service layer.
I even tried hardcoding the URL in the test class but still its failing
Says - URI is not absolute.
I hit the URL with Postman its working fine.
What would be an ideal fix for this case?
Ideally the url should never be called as we are returning the mock object.
Tried

```
When( mockRestTemplate.
    postForEntity(
     any(),any(),any()
    ).thenReturn(mockObject)
```

Comment: Where is `restTemplate` assigned? You are not showing working code (please read up on [mre])

Comment: so turns out restTemplate in service was not getting configured with the mock created in the test class. After i created a setter method inside my service class and set the mockRestTemplate exclusively from test, the issue resolved